# copy string to pointer failed in function in Clang

Tags: c, pointers

below clang code run in ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

I expect to output `ptr3=123` the same as var `ptr2`,
But the result is `ptr3=(null)`. How to modify the code that the result as I want?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void ptr_copy(char* d, char* s)
{
    d = s;
}

int main(){
    char *ptr = "123";
    char* ptr2;
    char* ptr3;

    ptr2 = ptr;
    ptr_copy(ptr3, ptr);

    printf("ptr2=%s\n", ptr2);
    printf("ptr3=%s\n", ptr3);

    // output 
    // ptr2=123
    // ptr3=(null)

}
```

Comment: You can try analyze your code with `printf("%p\n", (void *) ptrX);` which will print the pointer address.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a look at your "copy" function:

```
void ptr_copy(char* d, char* s)
{
    d = s;
}
```

In the function the variable `d` is a ***local*** variable. The assignment to it will be lost once the function returns and `d` goes out of scope and ends its life.

That leaves you with an uninitialized `ptr3` variable in the `main` function, and using it will lead to *undefined behavior*-

If you want to copy the pointer, you need to emulate *pass by reference* by passing a pointer to the pointer itself:

```
void ptr_copy(char** d, char* s)
{
    *d = s;
}
```

and call it as

```
ptr_copy(&ptr3, ptr);
```

Comment: Your solution is excellent! Is there a function to check an string is array type or pointer type?

Comment: @windman Once you have a pointer, that's really all you have. There's no way to know if it's a pointer to a single value, a pointer to the first element of an array, or a pointer to the middle of an array (or anywhere else really).

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a different `ptr_copy` function, something like this:

```
void ptr_copy(char** dst, char* src) {
    (*dst) = src;
}

ptr_copy(&ptr3, ptr);
```

the idea is that you fill the content of `ptr` to the place where `ptr3` is stored (hence `&ptr3`, not `ptr3`).

When you pass a pointer to a function, the value of that pointer is passed (that is an address a given pointer points to). Thus pointer `d` within `ptr_copy` is a *different* pointer than `ptr3` (it has a same value as `ptr3` but it resides in another part of the memory). That's why the assignment `d = s`, change an address `d` points to, but it doesn't do anything with `ptr3`.

Indeed consider a function

```
void value_copy(int d, int s) {
    d = s;
}
int i1 = 3;
int i3 = 2;
value_copy(i3, i1);
```

You don't expect `i3` to be equal to 3 after the call of `value_copy()`, do you?